# How to disable ie9 notification bar about default browser?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I have Internet Explorer 9 (german).
EVERY time I start it, a notification bar appears with the question (translated into english):
"Do you want to make IE9 the default browser?"
Then I click NO, but the next time I start the browser the questions comes up again.
How can I disable this behaviour?

Comment: Isn't there a checkbox labeled with something like "don't ask again"

Comment: Solved via registry here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222367/windows-registry-key-for-check-whether-ie-is-the-default-browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the right of the "no" option (to the default browser question) is a little menu arrow.
Click this and select "don't ask me again".

This should disable the question.

Comment: Oh my word. I have been tearing my hair out for weeks now. I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get to the screen I'm about to describe, but the easiest way I like is to just open IE, press the alt key (to show the menu bar in case it's not there), select the tools menu, and at the bottom of the list there should be a selection called "Internet Options". Select it and a new window will open. You can also get to this in the control panel too.

Now that the "Internet Properties" window is open, just select the "Programs" tab near the top. There are 7 tabs and you should be in the General tab when you open the window. Select the "Programs" tab way over to the right and you should then see a box (among other things) that says, "Tell me if Internet Explorer is not the default web browser." Clear the check mark, hit the apply button or just press OK. Now, whenever you open IE9 it won't ask you if you want to make it the default browser.

There is a similar setting in all web browsers but there is no standard way to deal with it. This is just for IE9 only.

I would also caution you to occasionally make IE9 your default browser in certain circumstances like if you have a program that needs IE plugins or IE itself in order to get updates or perform some other function. But for everything else, there's either Firefox or Opera.

Comment: Didn't work for Windows 8 on this PC.